# Expand emmet abbreviations without pressing TAB in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

This is my vs code's  settings.josn shows me regarding emmet.

```
 "emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact"
  },
  "emmet.showExpandedAbbreviation": "always",
  "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
```

I can use emmet abbreviations after pressing **TAB** key or clicking **Edit -> "emmet : expand abbreviation"**. But I want to know if there is a way to do it automatically when vs code is getting started. If anyone knows that kind of way please let us know.

Answer (score 0):

In VSCode go to

> "settings → Extensions → Emmet → Edit in settings.json" and add this in `settings.json` file

```json
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact",
    "typescript": "typescriptreact",
    "html":"html"
},
```